# aws amplify work with documentdb or document type nosql database

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-documentdb

So I am relatively new to AWS and AWS Amplify helped me write my backend app a lot. I know AWS Amplify does offer a NoSQL database direct connection, but that's connected to DynamoDB, which is also a NoSQL database, but it's not the type of NoSQL database I want. I want document type BSON NoSQL database. I was wondering is there any easy way to connect to AWS DocumentDB or MongoDB using AWS Amplify or do I need to use aws-sdk or something else for that? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a GraphQL API for Amazon DocumentDB and use this API as your amplify backend application as explained in this [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/create-or-re-use-existing-backend/q/platform/js#re-use-existing-appsync-graphql-api).

To create a GraphQL API for Amazon DocumentDB, you can use Lambda resolvers. Please refer to tutorial on using Lambda Resolvers [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html).

Amazon DocumentDB connection and related queries will be defined in the lambda function.